# Count value column iteratively for rows within column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      info_version  commits commitdates
18558       17.1.3       42  2017-07-14
20783       17.1.3       57  2017-07-14
20782       17.2.2       57  2017-09-27
18557       17.2.2       42  2017-09-27
18556       17.2.3       42  2017-10-30
20781       17.2.3       57  2017-10-30
20780       17.2.4       57  2017-11-27
18555       17.2.4       42  2017-11-27
20779       17.2.5       57  2018-01-10
```

I have a trivial issue, but somehow I am not able to find the function,I want to count the commits starting from value 42 till the last one, my desired output is something like this:

```
      info_version  commits commitdates    Commit_growth
18558       17.1.3       42  2017-07-14       42
20783       17.1.3       57  2017-07-14       109
20782       17.2.2       57  2017-09-27       166
18557       17.2.2       42  2017-09-27.      208
18556       17.2.3       42  2017-10-30       250
20781       17.2.3       57  2017-10-30       307
20780       17.2.4       57  2017-11-27       364
18555       17.2.4       42  2017-11-27.      406
20779       17.2.5       57  2018-01-10       463
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
data2 = data1[['info_version', 'commits', 'commitdates']].sort_values(by='info_version', ascending=True)
sum_row = data2.sum(axis=0)
```

But this gives me the entire count. This seems to be easy, but I am a bit stuck.

Comment: How did you get the `Commit_growth` to equal `109` on the second row ? I work it out to be `42 + 57 = 99` ??

Comment: I am sorry, it is indeed 99, calculation mistake on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `.cumsum()` should be suffice, 
because it looks like the `df` is already sorted by `info_version`

```
data1['Commit_growth'] = data1['commits'].cumsum()
```

**Here is the example code:**

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'info_version': ['17.1.3', '17.1.3', '17.2.2', '17.2.2', '17.2.3', '17.2.3', '17.2.4', '17.2.4', '17.2.5'],
                    'commits': [42, 57, 57, 42, 42, 57, 57, 42, 57],
                    'commitdates': ['2017-07-14', '2017-07-14', '2017-09-27', '2017-09-27', '2017-10-30', '2017-10-30', '2017-11-27', '2017-11-27', '2018-01-10']})

data1['Commit_growth'] = data1['commits'].cumsum()
print(data1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  info_version  commits commitdates  Commit_growth
0       17.1.3       42  2017-07-14             42
1       17.1.3       57  2017-07-14             99
2       17.2.2       57  2017-09-27            156
3       17.2.2       42  2017-09-27            198
4       17.2.3       42  2017-10-30            240
5       17.2.3       57  2017-10-30            297
6       17.2.4       57  2017-11-27            354
7       17.2.4       42  2017-11-27            396
8       17.2.5       57  2018-01-10            453
```

Comment: If i had to to cumsum on an entire dataset, will it work if i sort values by `info_version` ?

Comment: The cumsum will work on the values that are there (sorted or unsorted). So if you sort them, and then cumsum, it should cumsum on the sorted values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) but the output is different from yours :

```
data1["commitdates"]= pd.to_datetime(data1["commitdates"]) #only if not parsed yet
​
data2= (
         data1
            .loc[:, ["info_version", "commits", "commitdates"]]
            .sort_values(by=["info_version", "commitdates"])
            .assign(Commit_growth= lambda x: x["commits"].cumsum())
        )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(data2)

          info_version  commits commitdates  Commit_growth
    18558       17.1.3       42  2017-07-14             42
    20783       17.1.3       57  2017-07-14             99
    20782       17.2.2       57  2017-09-27            156
    18557       17.2.2       42  2017-09-27            198
    18556       17.2.3       42  2017-10-30            240
    20781       17.2.3       57  2017-10-30            297
    20780       17.2.4       57  2017-11-27            354
    18555       17.2.4       42  2017-11-27            396
    20779       17.2.5       57  2018-01-10            453
```

Comment: Thank you for this, yes I realized my output had calculation error on my part, sorry for the mistake!